# Convert a vector of pairs to a hash table / map

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap

I am currently trying to create a hash table from a `std::vector <std::pair<vector<int>, fs::path> >` within the pair, is each vector a key for an item being the path. Is there a smart in which i can convert it to `std::map`?

Comment: You have to provide a less functor for your `std::vector<int>`. The [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) needs a less functor to sort the entries by key. Have a look at [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (which is used by default) to get a clue how you can define your own.

Comment: A std::vector as key? Why?

Comment: @manni66 Why not? We use `vector`s e.g. as paths through graphs. To find duplicates we use `set<vector>` but we have to provide a less functor as well.

Comment: @Scheff _why not_ doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @manni66 Ah, OK - misunderstood you. You probably guess it might be an XY issue...

Comment: The key is a 512 feature vector... It has to be unique..

Answer (score 0):

Rather any type can be used as key of a `std::set` or `std::map` if the appropriate less functor is available. If the `std::less` (which is used by default) is not appropriate an own might be provided instead.

IMHO the most important: the less functor must provide a strict order of key values.

I made a simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate this `testLessVector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

// convenience: stream output of vector<int>
std::ostream& operator << (
  std::ostream &out, const std::vector<int> &values)
{
  out << '{';
  for (const int value : values) out << ' ' << value;
  out << " }";
  return out;
}

// the less functor
struct Less {
  bool operator()(
    const std::vector<int> &v1, const std::vector<int> &v2) const
  {
    const size_t size1 = v1.size(), size2 = v2.size();
    for (size_t i = 0, n = std::min(size1, size2); i < n; ++i) {
      if (v1[i] < v2[i]) return true;
      if (v1[i] > v2[i]) return false;
    }
    return size1 < size2;
  }
};

int main()
{
  // build some sample data
  std::set<std::vector<int>, Less> sample;
  sample.insert(std::vector<int>{ 2, 3, 1 });
  sample.insert(std::vector<int>{ 3, 1, 2 });
  sample.insert(std::vector<int>{ 3, 1, 2, 1});
  sample.insert(std::vector<int>{ 2, 1, 3 });
  sample.insert(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
  // print sample data sorted
  for (const std::vector<int> value : sample) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Tested in Cygwin on Window 10 (64 bit):

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o testLessVector testLessVector.cc

$ ./testLessVector 
{ 1 2 3 }
{ 2 1 3 }
{ 2 3 1 }
{ 3 1 2 }
{ 3 1 2 1 }

$
```

Live demonstration on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/CeSm2n)